# Can you remove the "View / Edit / Delete" links on a Lift CRUDify form?

Tags: scala, lift

I am throwing together a quick CRUDify app with Lift, and I need read-only access for one of the database tables.

I have researched how to remove that table's "Create" option from the navigation menu, by setting `calcCreateItem` to `Empty` in the mapper object.

However, to make it read-only I ALSO need to remove the "Edit" and "Delete" links on each row of that table's CRUDify form.  I would like to go ahead and remove the "View" link while I'm at it (all of the table's fields are already displayed on the List form)... but I can live with the "View" links if I have to.

Does anyone know how to make it such that records on a CRUDify "List" form do not contain the "View" / "Edit" / "Delete" links on the far-right of each row?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Kim's IfValue solution is probably the most concise though probably not the easiest to understand for a newbie. You could also just `override def _showAllTemplate` on your entity. It's defined as below in the Crudify trait, so you could just remove the link TDs. Note that even if the links don't appear in the template they would still be accessible so you need to block them from the SiteMenu. To do that it's better if you just override the menu locs rather then calcCreateItem methods.

```
override def createMenuLoc: Box[Menu] = Empty
override def editMenuLoc: Box[Menu] = Empty
override def viewMenuLoc: Box[Menu] = Empty
```

---

```
def _showAllTemplate =
<lift:crud.all>
<table id={showAllId} class={showAllClass}>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <crud:header_item><th><crud:name/></th></crud:header_item>
      <th>&nbsp;</th>
      <th>&nbsp;</th>
      <th>&nbsp;</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <crud:row>
      <tr>
        <crud:row_item><td><crud:value/></td></crud:row_item>
        <td><a crud:view_href="">{S.??("View")}</a></td>
        <td><a crud:edit_href="">{S.??("Edit")}</a></td>
        <td><a crud:delete_href="">{S.??("Delete")}</a></td>
      </tr>
    </crud:row>
  </tbody>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="3"><crud:prev>{previousWord}</crud:prev></td>
      <td colspan="3"><crud:next>{nextWord}</crud:next></td>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks!  I appreciated the other answer, but in all honesty I just didn't get it.  When I Googled for further information, the only thing I found was the [exact source code from which Kim's example was taken](http://swtsrv02.cs.hs-rm.de/redmine/projects/we-smlt/repository/revisions/13/diff/trunk/smlt/src/main/scala/de/hs_rm/cs/smlt/model/Exercise.scala)(!)... and even it had apparently been changed at some point.

Answer (score 0):

You can override `editMenuLocParams` and `deleteMenuLocParams` to remove the edit and delete links. Here is an example from a project of mine:

```
override def editMenuLocParams = 
  new Loc.IfValue[Exercise](deleteEditAllowed, errorAndRedirect _) :: 
    super.editMenuLocParams
```

See also the [scaladoc for Loc.IfValue](http://scala-tools.org/mvnsites/liftweb-2.4-M4/#net.liftweb.sitemap.Loc%24). `deleteEditAllowed` is a function that takes a Box of the mapper class and returns a boolean indicating whether editing is allowed. `errorAndRedirect` has type `() ⇒ LiftResponse`. It displays an error and redirects.